# How can I integrate Passkeys into my Wordpress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How can I code an integration possibly in php to integrate passkeys into wordpress. I will compile the passkey integration code into a plugin. But how can I create such an integration?

Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.